# magento1 admin panel new product add then error show 500 http error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, grid, admin-panel, product-grid

magento1 admin panel new product add then error show 500 http error.

SO GIVE ME SOLUTION PLEASE.

Mehul Kanjariya

Answer (score 0):

For the unexpected error (e.g 500), we should enable error reporting on the bootstrap:

**app/bootstrap.php**

```
ini_set('display_errors', -1) // Should enable error reporting with -1 value.
```

In your case, we need to check the places where you call your custom attributes which have been deleted.

Another way, we need to check the Apache error log.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache (I don't have much experience with nginx) you can watch the log and see what error is displayed in real time. Your log is probably located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/httpd/error.log`, if you haven't setup custom logs for your `vhosts`. To watch it in real time you should run `tail -f <path to log file>`. Post the output here so we can continue to help you debug the issue.